# Group json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, grouping

I want to group json array by first letter

This is my data records it quesry from sqlitedb

Ex :

```
[
   {"pid":2,"ID":1,"title":"aasas as"},
   {"pid":3,"ID":2,"title":"family"},
   {"pid":4,"ID":3,"title":"fat111"}
]
```

I need this output

```
{
    A: [{
        title: "aasas as",
        ID: 1
    }],
    F: [{
        title: "family",
        ID: 2
    }, {
        title: "fat111",
        ID: 3
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data = [
   {"pid":2,"ID":1,"title":"aasas as"},
   {"pid":3,"ID":2,"title":"family"},
   {"pid":4,"ID":3,"title":"fat111"}
];

var result = {},
    i, 
    len = data.length,
    key;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    key = data[i].title.substring(0, 1); // get first word from string
    
    if (!result[key]) { // if key does not exists in result, create it
        result[key] = [];
    }
    
    result[key].push(data[i]); // else push data
}

console.log(result);
```